# Для чего шаг acl at_step в конфигурации Squid?

Tags: proxy, squid

читаю [документацию](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice) по squid. Но не совсем понимаю как работает данный конфиг

```
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump monitoredSites !serverIsBank
ssl_bump splice all
```

В моём представлении приходит запрос от клиента на прокси, так как TCP connect выполняется всегда то он регистрируется в список acl под именем step1.
Далее те запросы которые попали в этот список проходят второй шаг TLS ClientHello, Где известен SNI.
Если сайт находится в списке monitoredSites то мы влезаем и расшифровываем запрос, но не те сайты которые в списке serverIsBank.
Все остальные запросы клиентов обрабатываем как TCP тунель, сращивая их с серверами назначения.

Мне не понятно зачем помещать все запросы при помощи acl SslBump1, если можно просто написать `ssl_bump peek all`. Тогда на первой итерации Squid заглянет в TCP запрос, где известен лишь адрес и порт, далее на втором шаге получит уже SNI и на третьем шаге будет совпадение с правилом bump, ну и все остальные не попавшие просто будут соединины